# Protractor Test: options to force refresh when URL hash changes

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing

In running some protractor tests, I need to refresh the browser in between tests.  I'm noticing that doesn't work when only the URL hash changes ([see here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4723)).

I tried calls to `.refresh()` or `.navigate.refresh()` to force a browser refresh.  That didn't seem to do anything.  Possibly because of the issue referenced above since only the hash changed?

I tried `.restart()`, that did open a fresh browser, but it seemed to restart tests and do way more than I'm looking for.

The closest option I've had luck with was doing a `.get()` to a completely different URL, and then another `.get()` with the hash changed URL (code below).  That did what I wanted in the browser, but for some reason the second `.get()` hangs.

What can I do to get a URL hash change to force a refresh?

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    //First GET (to a different hash)
    await browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);
});

it('should load ID from URL', async () => {
    //Load the signup URL
    let fakeId = '12345abcd';
    console.log("step 1: " + new Date().toISOString());
    await browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl + `#/signup?id=${fakeId}`);

    //BROWSER NAVIGATES PROPERLY, BUT NEVER GET THE CONSOLE OUTPUT BELOW
    console.log("step 2: " + new Date().toISOString());

    var loginButton = element(by.id('btnLoginHeader'));
    var untilLoginVisible = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(loginButton);
    await browser.wait(untilLoginVisible, 20000);

    //NEVER GET THE CONSOLE OUTPUT BELOW
    console.log("step 3: " + new Date().toISOString());

    //<snip>
    expect(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you change the hash property of ‘location’ object the browser never refreshes the page.

I think that a this scenario it is ok to force the full page reload via adding some ‘query-string’ to the path that is be fore the hash, that will load the page for sure.

Something like that:

```
    await browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl + `?_fake=1#/signup?id=${fakeId}`);
```

Comment: Good comment - this should help in many places, and is likely more "proper" URL structure (to put the query params before the hash).  I do have a few tests that have the exact same params and hashes though, so forcing a refresh (or 2 `.get()` requests in one test) is still something I need.

Comment: By that hash, I assume that you are using `Angularjs`, My suggestion will work on the scenario when you need `angulars` fake `search` part.